# High Charts - Set Solid Gauge Value from JSON

Tags: json, highcharts

I have created a solid gauge and I am trying to get the value for the gauge from a json request to a web service.

I'm just not sure how to set the y value from the json request?

Thanks for any advice

```
                    series: [{
                    name: 'Your Score',
                    borderColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
                    data: [{
                        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
                        radius: '100%',
                        innerRadius: '100%',
                        y: []
                    }],
```

this is the JSON request

```
                /* Send ajax request and get the value as response */
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "WebService.aspx?Action=Dashboard",
                context: document.body,
                success: function (response) {

                    var arr = $.parseJSON(response);

                    options.series[0].data[0].y = arr

                    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use update() <s>and redraw()</s> method:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "WebService.aspx?Action=Dashboard",
            context: document.body,
            success: function (response) {

                var arr = $.parseJSON(response);

                var chart = $('#your_chart_id').highcharts();
                chart.series[0].points[0].update(arr);                    

            }
        });
```

EDIT:
First get chart reference

EDIT:
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6yjr14x3/1/). redraw() is also not required

Comment: Thanks for helping, it didn't work though unfortunately

Comment: I attached working fiddle, verify ajax response by 'console.log(arr)'